# Регулярка для разбивания строки на группы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sql-server

Допустим, есть строка:

> AAAA1  XXX1 AAAA2 XXX1 AAA3

Как я могу с помощью регулярки получить 3 группы, использовав в качестве дилителя XXX1.

С помощью просмотра вперед\назад, что-то не получается это сделать...

Если бы делитель был бы из одного символа, то я бы сделал вот так например [^\$]+ и получил бы 3 группы.

**UPD**

Это я все пытаюсь провернуть на MS SQL 2008 R2, имея на руках CLR с регулярками, которая способна возвращать группы, которые подходят по регулярке. Допиливать CLR ради единичного случая не охота и мне интересно, можно ли это все сделать хитрой регуляркой.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто разделить по `XXX1`? `>>> 'AAAA1 XXX1 AAAA2 XXX1 AAA3'.split(' XXX1 ')
['AAAA1', 'AAAA2', 'AAA3']`

Comment: @gil9red мы не ищем легких путей. Просто, у меня CLRка для MS SQL и в ней нету этой возможности, а переделывать ее что-то не охота и я подумал, что может быть с помощью хитрой регулярки можно и с ее помощью справится.

Comment: А STRING_SPLIT (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) не подойдет? Можете в вопросе подробнее описать?

Comment: @gil9red слишком легко... У нас MS SQL 2008R2

Comment: Сурово... а если так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string ?

Comment: @gil9red да, можно и так. Но мне что-то захотелось посмотреть, как это будет выглядеть в виде регулярки.

Comment: обновите пожалуйста вопрос, длобавьте туда информацию про 2008R2 и т.д.

Comment: Так как вы собираетесь искать 1 *и более* совпадений, какой результат вы хотите получить? Строку с совпадениями через запятую? Добавить строчки в таблицу?

Comment: Хочу, что бы было найдено 3 совпадения: AAAA1, AAAA2, AAAA3

Comment: Возможно в вопросе надо уточнить понятие группа, так как `Group` может содержать несколько значений - [Captures](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures). Может надо получить одну `Group` с несколькими `Capture`?

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать [Group.Captures](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures)

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string input = "AAAA1 XXX1 AAAA2 XXX1 AAA3";
            string pattern = @"(?:(A+\d)(?:\ XXX1\ ?)?)+";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", match.Value);
                for (int ctr = 1; ctr < match.Groups.Count; ctr++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}:  {1}", ctr, match.Groups[ctr].Value);
                    int captureCtr = 0;
                    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[ctr].Captures)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}",
                                          captureCtr, capture.Value);
                        captureCtr++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Matched text: "AAAA1 XXX1 AAAA2 XXX1 AAA3"
   Group 1: "AAA3"
      Capture 0: "AAAA1"
      Capture 1: "AAAA2"
      Capture 2: "AAA3"
```